# How to find number of identical elements in array in ruby language

Tags: ruby

I have an array `a = [1, 2, 2, 4]` 
How can I find amount of duplicated elements in the array?
For example integer "2" appear twice in array, how can I find that?
I want the output like

```
There are 2 "2" in array.
```

Comment: What do you mean? Please explain better and provide an example of input and output.

Comment: If `a = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z']`, what do you want the result to be? `2`? `3`? `{1 => ['w', 'x'], 2 => ['y'], 3 => ['z']}`? Please try to be more specific when asking.

Comment: Im sorry about a bad written question, I was to leave urgently.

Comment: @KirillZhuravlov I have edited the answer according to the desired output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is premature. You need to try, then ask a specific question about what you tried. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]".

Comment: Several of the answers use [Enumerable#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) to count the number of instances in `a` of each element in `a.uniq`. That is a relatively expensive operation, as `a` must be traversed for each element of `a.uniq`. There are more efficient ways of doing that, such as using [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) or a counting hash, as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a number of non-uniq elements:

```
a.size - a.uniq.size
#=> 1
```

To get a count of non-uniq elements:

```
a.chunk(&:itself).reject { |chunk| chunk.last.one? }.flat_map(&:last).size
#=> 2
```

---

Acording to the edited question:

```
'There are ' + a.chunk(&:itself).reject { |chunk| chunk.last.one? }.map {|chunk| "#{chunk.last.size} \"#{chunk.first}\"" }.join(' and ') + 'in array.'
#=> "There are 2 "2" in array."
```

If there were more duplicated entries:

```
a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]
```

the output would look like:

```
There are 2 "1" and 2 "2" and 3 "3"in array.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 4,2]
count={}
a.each do |element|
  if (count[element]==nil)
    count[element]=1
  else
    count[element]+=1
  end
end
puts count
```

The output is:

```
{1=>1, 2=>3, 4=>1}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, I like to suggest that we should enforce good programming techniqes in our answers. Indentation is one of them. God knows how it helps when it comes to debugging a program.

Comment: Actually I was trying to add indentation ! but it didn't work :/. but yes I agree :)

Answer (score 1):

Making it a bit shorter than @SoulRebel:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 4,2]
count = {}
a.each { |e| count[e] == nil ? count[e] = 1 : count[e] += 1 }
puts count
```

The output is also

```
{1=>1, 2=>3, 4=>1}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should return the count of each element:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 4]
a.group_by { |number| number }.map { |key, value| [key, value.size] }.to_h
#=> {1=>1, 2=>2, 4=>1}
```

or shorter:

```
a.map { |num| [num, a.count(num)] }.uniq.to_h
#=> {1=>1, 2=>2, 4=>1}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is similar to a frequency distribution, i.e, you want to get the number of times each number or object is appearing in an array.

You can use `group_by` to do that for you:

```
a = [1,2,2,4]
# Use group_by to calculate frequency distribution

freq_dist = a.group_by { |el| el } # Returns a hash
# freq_dist = {1=>[1], 2=>[2, 2], 4=>[4]}

# To calcualte no of times 2 is repeated 
puts freq_dist[2].count
```

You can also write your own method using some array utilities.
First get all unique elements and map it to the number of times an element is repeated in the array:

```
a = [1,2,2,4]

# Get unique elements using uniq and map each element to it's count

a.uniq.reduce({}) { |result,el| result[el] = a.count el ; result }

# Gives {1=>1, 2=>2, 4=>1}
```

Here's another way to do this:

```
# This uses memoization 
a.inject({}) { |res,el| res[el] += 1; res}
```

For further reading see "[Building a Histogram](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ruby-cookbook/0596523696/ch05s12.html)".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a counting hash. See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) for the case where the default value is zero.

```
a = [2,5,3,2,5,5]

s = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }.
      reject { |_,v| v==1 }.
      map { |cnt, nbr| "#{nbr} #{cnt}" }.join(', ')
puts "There are #{s} in array"
```

prints

```
There are 2 2, 3 5 in array
```

The steps for computing `s` are as follows.

```
b = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
  #=> {2=>2, 5=>3, 3=>1} 
c = b.reject { |_,v| v==1 }
  #=> {2=>2, 5=>3} 
d = c.map { |cnt, nbr| "#{nbr} #{cnt}" }
  #=> ["2 2", "3 5"] 
s = d.join(', ')
  #=> "2 2, 3 5"
```